# Node.js child process isn't receiving stdin unless I close the stdin stream

Tags: node.js, stdin, child-process

I'm building a discord bot that wraps a terraria server in node.js so server users can restart the server and similar actions.  I've managed to finish half the job, but I can't seem to create a command to execute commands on the terraria server.  I've set it to write the command to the stdin of the child process and some basic debugging verifies that it does, but nothing apparently happens.

In the Node.js docs for child process stdin, it says "*Note that if a child process waits to read all of its input, the child will not continue until this stream has been closed via end().*"  This seems likely to be the problem, as calling the end() function on it does actually send the command as expected.  That said, it seems hard to believe that I'm unable to continuously send commands to stdin without having to close it.

Is this actually the problem, and if so what are my options for solving it?  My code may be found below.

```
const discordjs = require("discord.js");
const child_process = require("child_process");
const tokens = require("./tokens");

const client = new discordjs.Client();


const terrariaServerPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Terraria\\TerrariaServer.exe"
const terrariaArgs = ['-port', '7777', "-maxplayers", "8", "-world", "test.wld"]

var child = child_process.spawn(terrariaServerPath, terrariaArgs);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
client.on('disconnect', () => {
    client.destroy();
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.channel.name === 'terraria') {
        var msgSplit = msg.content.split(" ");
        if (msgSplit[0] === "!restart") {
            child.kill();
            child = child_process.spawn(terrariaServerPath, terrariaArgs);
            registerStdio();
            msg.reply("restarting server")

        }
        if (msgSplit[0] === "!exec") {
            msg.reply(msgSplit[1]);
            child.stdin.write(msgSplit[1] + "\n");
            child.stdin.end();
        }
    }
});

client.login(tokens.discord_token);
var registerStdio = function () {
    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`${data}`);
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`${data}`);
    });
}
registerStdio();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem by using the library [node-pty](https://github.com/Tyriar/node-pty).  As near as I can tell, the problem was that the child process was not reading the stdin itself and I was unable to flush it.  Node-pty creates a virtual terminal object which can be written to instead of stdin.  This object does not buffer writes and so any input is immediately sent to the program.